# Trendline for historical usage of "prick"

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

How can I view one of those handy-dandy trend lines for the historical usage of the word "prick"? I am currently editing a book and need to know when and how (or how common) the use of the word was to make sure it doesn't detract from the story's authenticity.

Thank you.

Comment: *prick* to mean what?

Comment: Prick has a variety of definitions. Unless we know which one you want, this can't be answered. Do you want the vulgar noun? The application of that noun to a person as an insult? The verb that means to pierce with a small hole?

Comment: In my opinion, the best research approach to follow is to look up the word in the OED (perhaps in your local library if you don't have a more convenient way to access it) There, you will find dated citations for each individual usage. For a query like this, which is relatively complex because of the need to tease apart the timelines for the different senses in which the word has been used, that will be a better method than using Ngrams, which can very easily generate misleading results.

Comment: If you are concerned with its more vulgar meaning then search Ngram try using a phrase such as: "he's a prick" or "is being a prick" otherwise your results will include all its verb and noun  meanings.

Comment: see this Ngram to have an idea https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+a+prick%2Cto+be+a+prick%2Cto+prick%2Che+pricked%2Cthe+prick&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20a%20prick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20a%20prick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20prick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20pricked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20prick%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can I view one of those handy-dandy trend lines for the historical usage of the word "prick"?

It's called a Google ngram. Look under https://books.google.com/ngrams

See Mr. Munn's answer for the advisability of doing this.

Comment: For a word like 'prick', which goes back all the way to Old English, Google ngrams is pretty much useless, since it has no way to distinguish between meanings of the the word, as Erik points out in the comments.